# Javascript - Connect to websocket when possible

Tags: javascript, websocket

In my application, I need to connect to my WebSocket server. The thing is - I don't know when that server is up. It can happen while the application itself is running. So I somehow need to monitor that port until I notice something like "a server is now listening on that port" after that I connect to the server automatically.

I could let the user press a button that tries to connect to the server
or I could keep trying to establish a connection using a `for` loop and a `timeout`. However, I think that would be a bad solution. Is there a better way?

Comment: Since you need to 'receive' an event from the backend theres only two ways to do it: checking the availability periodically (a `for` loop) or creating another websocket connection to update the availability information of the important websocket

Comment: Running a setup of a few hundred front-end servers, the way I'd handle this is a Redis server acting as a pub/sub. So if one WSS comes online, you'd publish to HTTP servers the where-abouts and how to connect. Then you can just event-stream it or show them on reload.